# $compile() does not fire in custom Angular directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module("example_module", [])
.directive("example_directive", function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element) {
      element.html('{{example}}');
      return function($scope) {
        $scope.example = "Hello world";
      };
    }
  };
});
```

and the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example_module">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example title</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/example.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div example_directive></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect the directive to compile to `Hello world`, but it compile to an empty string instead. Where is the error?

I could use `template` or a `link` function, but my goal here is to understand how the `compile` function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how angular handles directive names.  I've changed your example to match angular's naming conventions and put together a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/V8GCnUkkQ4zdAvCuJg26?p=preview)

```
angular.module("example_module", [])
.directive("exampleDirective", function() {
  return {
    compile: function(element) {
      element.html('{{example}}');
      return function($scope) {
        $scope.example = "Hello world";
      };
    }
  };
});

<body>
    <div example-directive></div>
</body>
```